# Python read and print and turkish characters

Tags: python, encode

I am trying to read a file or string in Python which has Hungarian or Turkish characters. I get an encode error.
Python code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
codestring = 'FERBAL KÖNYVVIZSGÁLÓI TANÁCSADÓ ÉS'
print(codestring)
```

Error:

```
codestring = 'FERBAL K�NYVVIZSG�L�I TAN�CSAD� �S'
                                             ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd6 in position 8: invalid continuation byte
```

Any idea how I can read and print or save the strings?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem on Ubuntu -- what operating system are you on? How did you create the utf-8 characters in the first place?

Comment: Maybe your python script file is not in utf-8? I can reproduce it when I save the code in latin1 encoding, but not in utf-8.

Comment: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` tells Python that your Python source file uses the UTF-8 encoding. The error message means that it does not actually do so.

Comment: I'm using windows, python 3.9, actually @j1-lee, it works when i changedmy python script to UTF-8, thanks

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you did for the next person with the problem, @beachball?

Comment: Based on the comments from above only change was that I saved the python script as UTF-8 encoding (I'm using textpad), i reran the python script and it worked.